# Is the set open?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Define a complex polynomial $p:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ where $\deg p=n\in\mathbb{N}$. \begin{equation} 
p(z) = \alpha_{n}z^{n}+\alpha_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots+\alpha_{1}z+\alpha_{0},\quad \alpha_{n}\neq0.
\end{equation}
Is the set $\mathcal{S}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|p(z)|>R,\arg p(z) \in(a,b)\}$, where $0\leq a<b\leq2\pi$ and $R>0$ large, open?

Comment: $p$ is continuous, so if $\mathcal{T} = \{ w \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert w\rvert > R, \arg w \in (a,b)\}$ is open, so is $\mathcal{S} = p^{-1}(\mathcal{T})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. Even if you allow $R=0$. That's because $\mathcal{S}$ is the preimage of the open set $\{z\in \mathbb C\ \mid |z|>R, \arg(z)\in(a,b) \}$ under the continuous polynomial $p$.

Recall a function is continuous if and only if the preimage of every open set is open.